# NSIS setup desktop icon, start menu icon and Abort/Retry/Ignore Error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, nsis

I made a PyQt5 application recently and built it using pyinstaller. I have made the zip file. Now I wanted to to use NSIS to get an installer. I went to the sample's page and copied the following code "Simple installer and uninstaller with start menu item" https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Simple_tutorials#Simple_installer_and_uninstaller_with_start_menu_item.

I have tried to read the docs but I 'm confused between what is the installation dir, is it where the installer files would be or where like after you install some software on windows in Program Files. All installation files are visible in C:/Program Files/[Some Software].Is it that folder? Also there is SetOutPath. I want the similar behaviour too i.e, the installer should have checkboxes for shortcut icon on desktop and start menu. It should point in C:\Program Files[Name of app] when user runs installer. Currently it is giving me Retry/Ignore/ Abort error when run with "a.nsi", the script with the copied code. Otherwise when I try to use the make installer with zip file option I get the nice installer but that doesnt place desktop icon or start menu icon and the default installation dir it shows is desktop.

```
Name "Mailer"
# define name of installer
OutFile "Mailer-install.exe"
# For removing Start Menu shortcut in Windows 7
RequestExecutionLevel user

# define installation directory
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES


# start default section
Section

    # set the installation directory as the destination for the following actions
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    File "Mailer.zip"
    # create the uninstaller
    WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    # point the new shortcut at the program uninstaller
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\new shortcut.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

# uninstaller section start
Section "uninstall"

    # first, delete the uninstaller
    Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

    # second, remove the link from the start menu
    Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\new shortcut.lnk"

# uninstaller section end
SectionEnd
```

```html
<h3> The logs if required</h3>
```

```
MakeNSIS v3.05 - Copyright 1999-2019 Contributors
See the file COPYING for license details.
Credits can be found in the Users Manual.

Processing config: C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\nsisconf.nsh
Processing default plugins: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi\*.dll"
 + Banner::destroy
 + Banner::getWindow
 + Banner::show
 + BgImage::AddImage
 + BgImage::AddText
 + BgImage::Clear
 + BgImage::Destroy
 + BgImage::Redraw
 + BgImage::SetBg
 + BgImage::SetReturn
 + BgImage::Sound
 + Dialer::AttemptConnect
 + Dialer::AutodialHangup
 + Dialer::AutodialOnline
 + Dialer::AutodialUnattended
 + Dialer::GetConnectedState
 + InstallOptions::dialog
 + InstallOptions::initDialog
 + InstallOptions::show
 + LangDLL::LangDialog
 + Math::Script
 + StartMenu::Init
 + StartMenu::Select
 + StartMenu::Show
 + System::Alloc
 + System::Call
 + System::Copy
 + System::Free
 + System::Get
 + System::Int64Op
 + System::Store
 + System::StrAlloc
 + TypeLib::GetLibVersion
 + TypeLib::Register
 + TypeLib::UnRegister
 + UserInfo::GetAccountType
 + UserInfo::GetName
 + UserInfo::GetOriginalAccountType
 + VPatch::GetFileCRC32
 + VPatch::GetFileMD5
 + VPatch::vpatchfile
 + advsplash::show
 + nsDialogs::Create
 + nsDialogs::CreateControl
 + nsDialogs::CreateItem
 + nsDialogs::CreateTimer
 + nsDialogs::GetUserData
 + nsDialogs::KillTimer
 + nsDialogs::OnBack
 + nsDialogs::OnChange
 + nsDialogs::OnClick
 + nsDialogs::OnNotify
 + nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog
 + nsDialogs::SelectFolderDialog
 + nsDialogs::SetRTL
 + nsDialogs::SetUserData
 + nsDialogs::Show
 + nsExec::Exec
 + nsExec::ExecToLog
 + nsExec::ExecToStack
 + nsisdl::download
 + nsisdl::download_quiet
 + splash::show

!define: "MUI_INSERT_NSISCONF"=""

Changing directory to: "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder (3)\f"

Processing script file: "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder (3)\f\a.nsi" (ACP)
Name: "Mailer"
OutFile: "Mailer-install.exe"
InstallDir: "$PROGRAMFILES"
Section: ""
SetOutPath: "$INSTDIR"
File: "Mailer.zip" [compress] 57197161/57534535 bytes
WriteUninstaller: "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
CreateShortcut: "$SMPROGRAMS\new shortcut.lnk"->"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"  icon:,0, nwd=0, showmode=0x0, hotkey=0x0, comment=
SectionEnd
Section: "uninstall"
Delete: "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
Delete: "$SMPROGRAMS\new shortcut.lnk"
SectionEnd

Processed 1 file, writing output (x86-ansi):
warning 7998: ANSI targets are deprecated
Processing pages... Done!
Removing unused resources... Done!
Generating language tables... Done!
Generating uninstaller... Done!

Output: "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder (3)\f\Mailer-install.exe"
Install: 1 page (64 bytes), 1 section (2072 bytes), 5 instructions (140 bytes), 40 strings (726 bytes), 1 language table (198 bytes).
Uninstall: 1 page (128 bytes), 1 section (2072 bytes), 3 instructions (84 bytes), 39 strings (617 bytes), 1 language table (194 bytes).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               36352 / 37888 bytes
Install code:                    728 / 2568 bytes
Install data:               57197165 / 57534547 bytes
Uninstall code+data:             909 / 1409 bytes
CRC (0x02F0CF53):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                 57235158 / 57576416 bytes (99.4%)

1 warning:
  7998: ANSI targets are deprecated
```

Comment: Also, I have seen other answers on stackoverflow but they get into functions and other things and currently I have already spent  lot of time in learning PyQT , pyinstaller. I would be obliged if someone can help me with this. Also I couldn't understand the nsis language much and learning it would take further more days and I really want to distribute the software fast.I require it badly.

Comment: The Microsoft guidelines say that you should not create shortcuts on the users $Desktop, only in the Start Menu. And the shortcut should not point to the uninstaller.

Comment: @Anders but if you use any software these days it often shows checkboxes during install to allow the user to put a Desktop icon. StartMenu is good but there are some softwares which I use a lot and would not like to waste seconds in the search menu(typing and wasting for selecting, loading etc) .

Comment: I just told you what the Microsoft guidelines are. If you want the desktop option, just add another Section and use $Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a fatal change in the example script, you changed `InstallDir` to `$PROGRAMFILES` and you cannot write to `$PROGRAMFILES` if you are not a elevated administrator!

To give the user the option to create the shortcut or not, put it in a separate `Section` and add a components page:

```
Name "MyApp"
OutFile "MyAppSetup.exe"
Unicode True
RequestExecutionLevel Admin ; Request UAC elevation
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\$(^Name)"

Page Components
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Uninstpage UninstConfirm
Uninstpage InstFiles

!include LogicLib.nsh

!macro EnsureAdminRights
  UserInfo::GetAccountType
  Pop $0
  ${If} $0 != "admin" ; Require admin rights on WinNT4+
    MessageBox MB_IconStop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ; ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
    Quit
  ${EndIf}
!macroend

Function .onInit
  SetShellVarContext All
  !insertmacro EnsureAdminRights
FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
  SetShellVarContext All
  !insertmacro EnsureAdminRights
FunctionEnd


Section "Program files (Required)"
  SectionIn Ro
  SetOutPath $InstDir ; Sets the output directory for File instructions
  WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
  File "/oname=$InstDir\MyApp.exe" "${NSISDIR}\Bin\MakeLangId.exe" ; Pretend that we have a real application to install
SectionEnd

Section "Start Menu shortcut"
  CreateShortcut /NoWorkingDir "$SMPrograms\$(^Name).lnk" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
SectionEnd


Section -Uninstall
  Delete "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
  Delete "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
  RMDir "$InstDir"

  Delete "$SMPrograms\$(^Name).lnk"
SectionEnd
```

Note: This is a slightly modified version of the [install-shared.nsi example script](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Examples/install-shared.nsi). That script also registers the uninstaller with the Control Panel/Settings App which you should also do in a real installer.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I asked this I didn't know about the NSIS Script generator but after a bit(or a lot) of googling I found it out and I packaged the product. Nevertheless your code will definitely enhance my skills since I can understand the script and use it to customize the installer to give better user experience.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I chose Program Files because I want to learn software dev and all softwares live in Program Files only.